# Change WordPress search to produce WooCommerce search results only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like:

http://www.gadgetgogo.co.uk/?s=ipod

to return as:

http://www.gadgetgogo.co.uk/?s=ipod&post_type=product

So when using searches (slider banner and default WordPress search) it produces the second URL.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for similar solution as you but couldn't find any and at last I combined last few answers that I read here and got this working fine as I wanted.

Add below code in your theme's functions.php file

```
    function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) && ($_GET['post_type'] != 'product') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . "&post_type=product" );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

hope it will help you and others.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently current WooCommerce versions only consider a search query a product search (and render using the appropriate template), if `$query->is_post_type_archive( 'product' )` is true, so the key is to set not only the `post_type`, but the `is_post_type_archive` property as well, and to do it **before** WooCommerce loads its filter (default priority of 10), so with a priority of 9 or smaller.

Example to add into `funtions.php`:

```php
function my_search_filter($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search && ! is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
        $query->is_post_type_archive = true;
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_search_filter', 9);
```

Please note, that this code will override all searches as product serach, so if you have other searches as well, implement appropriate checks at the begining of `my_search_filter`.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this line to top of `search.php`

```
$_GET['post_type'] = 'product'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply aidinMC, unfortunately I can't get it to work by placing it on the top line. Is there a particular section I should add it to?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using pre_get_posts filter. Add below code in your theme's `functions.php file`

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_by_product_only' );

    function search_by_product_only( $query ) {

        // check if search query only
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'product') ); // here you can add multiple post types in whcih you want to search
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dipmala, unfortunately I can't get this to work either. Am I just dropping this into functions.php?

Comment: Yes correct and it should working because its tested code

Comment: Apologies dipmala it does work in one respect but not exactly how I want it to (I should reframe my question). I already have the search only showing products but I need the URL to change. For some reason when using the Avada theme it shows two different page varieties for these two search results (you can see this in the example links above), is there a way to change the URL?

Comment: Kindly share the code or screenshot how you use search form ?

Comment: Here is the code - https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ade690fc170d975f78dac3981/images/1aa74fdf-20fd-4849-957e-c4a49a289a5b.png

&

https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ade690fc170d975f78dac3981/images/6f7249f3-f4a7-4c72-98cb-e5b34864215a.png

And these screenshots show the difference in style when using the WooCommerce search widget and the default WordPress search widget (WooCommerce search is the desired look for all searches)

https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ade690fc170d975f78dac3981/images/59cad7e0-7a26-48d0-9202-69eba023838b.png

&

To follow...

Thanks so much dipmala.

Comment: https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ade690fc170d975f78dac3981/images/8c1c802c-2745-4290-af3d-b0bd8f7a8e54.png